# In R, how do you convert string representations of dates that have days with attached suffixes?

Tags: r, string, date

I'm converting data I'm scraping from a web page into a data table for further processing. The trouble is I can't quite figure out how to convert the dates. They come in one of two formats (I'll use examples because I'm not sure how to generalize for you in a way that's clear):

`"November 11th"`
`"December 1st (2015)"`

I have read the documentation for `as.Date`,`as.POSIXct`, and `as.POSIXlt` and I can't manage to write a format string that consistently handles these cases. The trailing suffix always seems to stump the format string, especially in the latter case. Luckily I think I can consistently predict which version I'll get at any one time, so if I have to write two different conversation functions/format strings that's cool.

Comment: There's no single function support to multiple Date formats (except for handling both YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY/MM/DD. I think that the `lubridate` package has some further  functions that do auto-detection, but I suspect it's not for those formats. You might , however, be able to look at that code to get ideas for building your own strategies.

Comment: Note that `as.Date("December 1st (2015)", "%B %dst (%Y)")` will work for your second one but the endings "nd" and "rd" will not be recognized for '3rd" or "2nd". You could probably strip the possible trailing 2 letter combos with a `gsub`-pattern of "st|nd|rd|th"

Comment: As @42 suggested, try formatting the strings before parsing (using `strptime` , ...) . I would also remove the brackets, or other punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub` with `regex` to capture the key words/numbers, combined with `as.Date` to convert to date:

For the first format, adding `2015` as year:

```
as.Date(paste0(sub("(\\w+)\\s(\\d+).+", "\\1-\\2", d1), "-2015"), format="%B-%d-%Y")
[1] "2015-11-11"
```

For the second format

```
as.Date(sub("(\\w+)\\s(\\d+).+\\s\\((\\d{4})\\).*", "\\1-\\2-\\3", d2), format="%B-%d-%Y")
[1] "2015-12-01"
```

*data:*

```
d1 <- "November 11th"
d2 <- "December 1st (2015)"
```